# Maximizing internal frame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

Does internalFrameIconified works only after internalFrameDeiconified?
And when I iconfy it diplayes Minimized..Is it a java bug?
Can we call the maximize method before minimizing it?

```
    //  add the intrenal window frame event..
        InternalFrameListener internalFrameListener = new InternalFrameListener() {
        InternalFrameEvent e;
        public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent e) {
             System.out.println("Opened");
        }

        public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        }

        public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Closed");
        }

        public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
           System.out.print("Maximised");
         }

        public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Minimised");
       }

        public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {
         System.out.println("Activated");
       }

       public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {
         System.out.println("DeActivated");
        }
     };
    interFrame.addInternalFrameListener(internalFrameListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply print wrong messages from the right methods.

```
    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Maximised"); // Should be "Iconified"
    }

    public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Minimised"); // Should be "Deiconified"
    }

    //...
```

and so on...

I mean, that the printed text doesn't correspond to what happens with the internal frame.
When the internal frame is *deiconified* the corresponding method of the `InternalFrameListener` prints "**Mininmised**", because you make him to print that wrong message.
The same thing with other methods of your `InternalFrameListener`.
That's why you can't understand what's really going on.

Here is the correct code of the `InternalFrameListener` with correct prints:

```
InternalFrameListener internalFrameListener = new InternalFrameListener() {

    public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Opened");
    }

    public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Closing");
    }

    public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Closed");
    }

    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Iconified");
    }

    public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Deiconified");
    }

    public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Activated");
    }

    public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Deactivated");
    }
 };
 interFrame.addInternalFrameListener(internalFrameListener);
```

Comment: @ MockerTim I am sorry i am a newbie to java..Can you please elaborate?